# SSO Login to Gmail

Tags: java, javascript, google-api

I am Working on Google Data api. I am taking credentials from user and displaying their events and Meetings.But My requirement is to make their login SSO. Means once they entered their credentials in my application they are automatically logged-in into Gmail.

How to make their login Single Sign on?

I am using java and Javascript.

Comment: "I am taking credentials from". What? You are taking their Google credentials? So you are asking them to violate the terms and conditions of their Google account? Stop immediately. If you want access to some data in someone's Google account, then use their OAuth API.

Comment: Ya. I should use that .Thanks for ur Comment !!

Comment: Like Quentin wrote, use google's login and do **not** grab the users credentials yourself. -- https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID?hl=de-DE

Comment: Calm down downvoters. He is doing something wrong (asking for the user credentials), but that is no reason to downvote the question. This is a legitimate question, precisely because it is something that a lot of people could get wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your requirement this - Once the google logs into your appreciation, he automatically gets logged into google and vice-versa.
                 If this is your requirement, you can use SAML 2.0 for implementing SSO. Google becomes the ID provider and your application is the service provider. When you want to log into your service(your application), you will be **redirected** to the google login page where google will authenticate you and set the necessary cookies will be set in your browser. then next time when you go to gmail.com, it sees that the cookies are already set and it automatically logs you in. The Vice-Versa of this is also true.